# iPad:Study basics for iPad development?

Tags: ipad

sorry if this question is being repeated. May i know from where i can learn entire iPad development practice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this book: http://www.pragprog.com/titles/sfipad/ipad-programming

Book is still in beta and only a few chapters are available.

Comment: Note that this book assumes that you already know how to do iPhone programming.  It only talks about what's new with the iPad.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know a bit about iPhoneOS development, check Apple's [iPad Programming Guide](http://www.ithaca.edu/barr/Student/CS390/docs/iPadProgrammingGuide.pdf).

(Knowing iPhone is not essential, but it's easier to start from it if you know nothing about the ObjC and Cocoa Touch stuff, and there's more tutorials targeting iPhone.)

Comment: Thanks Kenny. I am basically an iPhone developer. This should be enough for me.